# More than 255 characters for input link type in Power Apps and Lists

Tags: ms-office, powerapps

I've created a list with a link type column and connected to my power app. I'm having troubles when the link has more than 255 characters.

I've read the Microsoft documentation and there is not information about limits. Does anyone know anything about?

I hope to know how to configure the list to accept links with more than 255 characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The limit is indeed 255 characters and the best you can do to replace the column with a multiline text column. Then you can use workarounds to imitate the Hyperlink column's:

[One possible solution from Manuel Gomes](https://manueltgomes.com/microsoft/sharepoint/how-to-create-hyperlink-more-than-255-characters/)